# How to intercept instructions sent to the CPU

Tags: c++, cpu, intercept, opcode, instructions

I'm looking for a way to intercept instructions sent to the cpu.

More specifically op-codes that are being sent in and what thread sent them in.

Comment: ...impossible? Or, better, not realistic without much time and money

Comment: what do you suggest? developing a hardware device to do the job?

Comment: @padadp a) A intercepting device for all pins of CPU and RAM. WIll be very expensive, but possible. b) Manually reading/understanding of every single byte in the captured CPU output and the corresponding RAM state, and how they belong together, so that you can filter your thread and it´s variables out. Even in a single busy second, there is probably way too much data for your whole life. The binaries on the HDD will help, but it´s still *much* work. (You just found the reason why criminal and/or government hackers won´t do something like this on this precision level.)

Answer (score 4):

Run the code with a debugger attached (it doesn't have to be an interactive debugger; it does not even have to use the operating system's [debugger](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679288(v=vs.85).aspx), though that may be the easiest way to write the code), or run it in a CPU emulator, like [bochs](http://bochs.sf.net).

Comment: Downvoting is fine, but if you do, please take the time to comment why.

Comment: It was me, because strictly this is no solution (debugger isn´t the whole system and different from the real thing after all, and Bochs can´t fulfill the thread thing (or can it?)), but i reverted it again because this is the best it can get.

Comment: What i'm looking for is something more wide, like a system level driver to determine what instructions are coming from where.

Comment: @papadp Just assuming you can inject something in the kernel lowlevel enough to get everything sent to the CPU. Then the first opcode from somewhere will trigger your opcode processing code *which consists of more opcodes* The first opcode of your code will trigger your code again ... endless recursion. And such a lowlevel "driver" is impossible anyways.

Comment: @papadp Well, you *can* run the whole OS in an emulator. I don't think you get something closer to what you describe.

Comment: say it would be a driver that gets all the opcodes fed into it, I could filter out all opcodes coming in from the thread my code is running in which will prevent the code from looping.

Comment: @papadp And how do you even recognize "your" opcodes? (But, again, such a driver within the hardware OS is impossible)

Comment: @papadp That's almost the thing which is usually called a virtual machine. I don't see any advantage over a traditional virtual machine, which is easier to implement - not even mentioning *that someone else already did that for you.*

Comment: it would recognize my opcodes and ignore them based on the thread im running from, lets say it's 1234, in that case everything coming from thread 1234 will be ignored.

Comment: do you know of a way to link up against the vms cpu in a similiar fashion to what I described?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Dynamic Instrumentation. Use something like [Intel PIN](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) to instrument your application code at an instruction level and [use the API to get the instruction opcode](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/53271/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__GEN__IA32.html#g82b583eb54370b90eb16013b9ceccb0a) of the instruction being executed.

Comment: Well, there are some differences. But it is mostly ease of use.I assumed that you wanted to do something at runtime with the opcodes. Apart from doing things easily (for injecting code at runtime, a debugger is like trying to fix a car with a screwdriver. Possible, but not worth the effort) and at various granularities( not just function level granularity), you can do things at run-time (eg. depending on whether a branch falls through or goes to the else block, which is not easily done in GDB.

Comment: What technology does PIN utilize? I mean, does it utilize the windows debugging mechanism?